# What is the difference between width and breadth?

Tags: word-stress

I have looked this in dictionaries and they both mean: a distance from side to side.

I looked in google and the links say that they have a similar meaning with a slight difference but none pf them clearly explains what is that difference.

I understand that they are synonyms so please don't tell me that again.  I'm specifically looking for the slight difference in their usage. Please explain that to me with some examples.

Comment: The answers below are what Wikipedia would call "original research." I'll also add from my personal interpretation, but that's why this is a comment, not an answer. I think breadth sounds more poetic and almost archaic. Contrary to answers below, you can certainly use breadth with either precise measures, literally, or figuratively. But, due to us associating it with older writing, I think this is why people think of it more toward the figurative (Abul) and imprecise (Jim) end of the spectra. It's certainly not limited to poetic or archaic use, but not as everyday-use sounding as width.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since *width* and *breadth* derive from *wide* and *broad* we can look at these words for more clarification.

From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broad):

> Synonym Discussion of BROAD
>
> *broad, wide, deep* mean having horizontal extent.
> *Broad* and *wide* apply to a surface measured or viewed from side to side < a broad avenue >.
> *Wide* is more common when units of measurement are mentioned < rugs eight feet wide > or applied to unfilled space between limits < a wide doorway >.
> *Broad* is preferred when full horizontal extent is considered < broad shoulders >.
> *Deep* may indicate horizontal extent away from the observer or from a front or peripheral point < a deep cupboard > < deep woods >.

Comment: An example: _"Developing the technology to measure the width of a particle that small vastly expanded the breadth and depth of our knowledge of physics."_ I just made that up to use width and breadth in the same sentence, so it's not necessarily a true statement.

Answer (score 3):

One is about practical physical measurement, as in:

> 'the tailor would measure the width of a piece of cloth'.

And the breadth is a figurative speech meaning like:

> 'I searched the length and breadth of this place for that missing pen'.

Answer (score 2):

Since they both indicate some form of measurement, let us first contrast both words with length. So imagine a square. In this case, width, breadth and length are all equal and are pretty interchangeable (i.e. synonymous).

Now imagine a rectangle. Typically length  is used to describe the "longest" side and the "shorter side" can be described as the breadth as in in "the length and breadth of …".  So where does that leave width? Well if I had to say "the breadth and width of …" then I would assume breadth still stands for the shorter side and width for the longer side. However, if someone were to say "the length and width of " then of course width then becomes synonymous to breadth.

Now in everyday use… imagine you are standing next to and facing a road (waiting for, say, a bus). The "length" of the road is the distance measured along its curb, and would in all likelihood, be measured in kilometers. The distance from one curb to the other, this distance you cover crossing the road, is typically referred to as the width of the road and rarely as the breadth of the road — unless you are standing in the middle of the road with your arms outstretched towards the curbs… you could poetically say the breadth of the road.

So when to use breadth in common everyday language… well imagine a cube instead of a square. One can easily say the box is x centimeters wide (width), y centimeters long (length) and z centimeters high (height). Try to use "broad" to mean "breadth" in that sentence and you will sound archaic. But then again most people in measuring a cuboid would say width, height and breadth, eschewing length altogether.

So go on. Enjoy the quirks of the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I've always understood width and breadth to be synonymous with breadth just being an older English word.

Width referring to the 'wide'
Breadth referring to the 'broad'

Answer (score 0):

we used to call it breadth in my Native country Nepal. But here in United States, people call it Width. I didn’t know about this before I moved here. They are same.... Take this as an example: Rectangle has Length 10 cm, Breadth 5cm, and the Height 6 cm. The area of rectangle in this case is equals to Length * Breadth * Height thus, 10*5*6 = 300cm. Similarly, Area of rectangle is also refers to Length * Width * Height 10*5*6 =300cm. Therefore, depending on what part of the world you live in, name varies. Breadth and Width are same. I think it’s probably because in Nepal, we follow British English (old), and USA likes to make it more fancy. So, whichever ways teacher taught u, use that while taking test or quiz.

Answer (score -1):

I think we usually use breadth in two dimensional figures and width in three dimensional figures

Comment: Actually, I usually see _length_ and _width_ (or _length_ and _height_) in [two dimensions](http://thinkmath.edc.org/resource/measurement-length-width-height-depth), with _breadth_ added as the [third](https://www.amnh.org/ology/features/stufftodo_einstein/threed_dimension.php).

Comment: @J.R. They occur to indicate vastness of a plane in the idiom "the length and breadth of the land".